# Python - Data Analysis, finding key value matches between multiple python dictionaries containing python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I've been tasked with creating a program to take 3 data sets (.csv files, probably) containing personal info as input, parse them, and then search for matches. The real-world purpose is to search for conflicts of interest between 3 separate law firms.

My super high level plan is to parse the relevant columns into dictionaries containing personal information for each individual, for example:

```
{lname: jones, fname: matt, dob: 01-02-1990, addr1: 28 sheffield dr}
```

I would then feed each of the personal info dictionaries into a larger superset dictionary for each law firm, like this one (which represents 1 of the 3 larger container dictionaries, each one to represent one of the law firms):

```
{{lname: jones, fname: matt, dob: 01-02-1990, addr1: 28 sheffield dr}, {lname: kalinski, fname: fred, dob: 01-02-1980, addr1: 28 purple st}, {lname: kyle, fname: ken, dob: 05-01-1978, addr1: 28 carlisle dr}}
```

Finally, the task is  to find matches and identify individuals who exist in more than 1 of the "container/superset" dictionaries that represent each law firm.

I was thinking of matching 'last name', and 'date of birth' to identify a "soft match", and could then feed the matching personal info dictionaries into some other object to be further processed/checked. My main objective right now is to validate a sound plan for how I should approach this.

So, essentially, I need to find matching key/value pairs between one dictionary of dictionaries, and another dictionary of dictionaries.

So I'm wondering...

1. Any advice on my high level plan? Any glaring issues with my logic flow? I'm no data scientist, not even a professional developer so I would greatly appreciate it if anybody more experienced with this type of project might have something to add.
2. I know pandas is a popular lib used for large scale data analysis. Would pandas help me achieve what I'm trying to do here? Any other libraries or modules that come to mind for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some techniques to investigate:

1. groupby
2. duplicated

### Importing libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
```

### Preparing test data

```
text_data = '[{"lname": "jones", "fname": "matt", "dob": "01-02-1990", "addr1": "28 sheffield dr"}, {"lname": "kalinski", "fname": "fred", "dob": "01-02-1980", "addr1": "28 purple st"}, {"lname": "kyle", "fname": "ken", "dob": "05-01-1978", "addr1": "28 carlisle dr"}, {"lname": "jones", "fname": "matt", "dob": "01-02-1990", "addr1": "new address"}, {"lname": "kyle", "fname": "ken", "dob": "05-01-1979", "addr1": "other address"}]'

json_data = json.loads(text_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
```

The dataframe so far is:

```
>>> df
      lname fname         dob            addr1
0     jones  matt  01-02-1990  28 sheffield dr
1  kalinski  fred  01-02-1980     28 purple st
2      kyle   ken  05-01-1978   28 carlisle dr
3     jones  matt  01-02-1990      new address
4      kyle   ken  05-01-1979    other address
```

### Grouping by

```
>>> df.groupby(["lname", "dob"]).count()

                     fname  addr1
lname    dob
jones    01-02-1990      2      2   <- DUPLICATE
kalinski 01-02-1980      1      1
kyle     05-01-1978      1      1   <- SAME NAME
         05-01-1979      1      1   <- BUT, DIFFERENT DOB
```

Not as easy as groupby, let's see the duplicate method

### Duplicate method

```
>>> idx = np.where(df['lname'].duplicated(keep=False) & df['dob'].duplicated(keep=False))
```

And the `idx` content

```
>>> (array([0, 3]),)
```

Backing to dataframe

```
>>> df.iloc[idx]

   lname fname         dob            addr1
0  jones  matt  01-02-1990  28 sheffield dr
3  jones  matt  01-02-1990      new address
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you. Leaving the question unanswered for now in case I might get any additional input, but I think this is a phenominal answer, Thank you